# Cannot align to center images inside an ul element for internet explorer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this website [www.bestfamily.gr](https://www.bestfamily.gr) in wordpress

In **Chrome** displays normally
off course in **Internet Explorer** not. The main issue I notice is the images inside list elements are not centered.

**How should I write my css** to solve the problem?
thank you

Comment: Please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this style on you img's in your list:

```
ul.products li.product img {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

IE won't recognize the `display: -webkit-inline-box;`, so change it to `display: inline-block;` which both browsers will honor.

Comment: You are magnificent :)